# Ionic - Scheduled notifications & update it

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am writing a simple application who get available jobs from a backend ( you can put some filter to this job for example category, city ... ).

The filter can be saved, and if they are, the user register to a local scheduled notification to be able to receiv push if some new jobs are available for his filters.

The thing is, when I trigger the notification handle, I call the backend and check if the data.length are equal, if they I want to cancel this notification and schedule a new one for the next day.

Here my code working with a minute schedule push :

```
//register
  //on configure la notification
                  var now = new Date().getTime();
                  var _1MinFromNow = new Date(now + 60000);
                  $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
                    id: 1,
                    at: _1MinFromNow,
                    message: "Les jobs pour vos filtres ont changés, jetez y un petit coup d'oeil",
                    title: "Jobs rafraichies",
                    autoCancel: true,
                    data: { "nbJobs" : $scope.jobs.length}
                  });

    //trigger
    $cordovaLocalNotification.on("trigger", function (notification) {
            var promises = [];

            promises.push($scope.getAllJobs(true));
            //permet d'attendre le retour de getAllJobs
            $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
                $scope.jobs = results[0];

            }).finally(function(){
                if (notification.id != 1)
                    return;
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                var _1MinFromNow = new Date(now + 60000);

                if(notification.data.nbJobs == $scope.jobs.length){
                    $cordovaLocalNotification.isPresent(1).then(function(present) {
                        if(present){

                            $cordovaLocalNotification.update({
                               id: 1,
                               data: { "nbJobs" : $scope.jobs.length},
                               at: _1MinFromNow

                            });
                        }


                    });
                   return;
                }


                $cordovaLocalNotification.update({
                    id: 1,
                    data: { "nbJobs" : $scope.jobs.length},
                    at: _1MinFromNow

                });
            });


        },this);
```

Currently i am trying to do this with IOS.
I already use the every parameter, but if i put minute, i will be spam each minute with a notification.

If someone could help me :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: after some investigations, this is related to cordovaLocalNotification:trigger. This event is not currently working ( when I use schedule it's work ). if someone have an idea